# Sorting almost-duplicate lines by their share of identical beginning characters

Tags: bash, zsh, sorting, gnu

Is there a *nix tool/way to show each two lines (possibly adjacent via sort) that are almost duplicate top-ordered by the number of similar characters in same positions between each of those to lines ? For example for this list:

```
alpha
Omega2
candy3
alpine
Omega23
```

It will show:

```
Omega2
Omega23
alpha
alpine
candy3
```

because `alpha` and `alpine` share the same starting string `alp`. And so is `Omega2` the identical beginning string for `Omega2` and `Omega23`. But since 'candy3' does not have a couple because it does not share similar start with any other lines it is shown last. Also the more beginning-characters a pair of lines share the more upward will they be put.

Comment: How to sort `foo1`, `foo2`, `fom1` and `fom2`?

Comment: @KamilMaciorowski since each pair share the same number of initial letters (3) it doesn't really matter but alphanumeric is also possible

Comment: But regardless of the order of these two pairs, there will be an "inner" pair that shares only 2 letters. According to your requirements a pair sharing 2 should be later on the list. What about the "outer" pair?

Comment: @KamilMaciorowski I'm not sure I understand which inner pair you are talking about. I only care about the first "matches" , which is why I wrote "beginning characters"

Comment: OK, to be clear, let's assume the sorted sequence is `fom1`, `fom2`, `foo1`, `foo2`. The "inner" pair is `fom2`+`foo1`, it should be after `foo1`+`foo2`. Then there is the "outer" pair: `fom1`+`foo2`; it doesn't appear as a pair (two adjacent lines) at all. The sorted list misses more pairs this way. The only pair that shares exactly 2 letters and actually appears as adjacent lines must be chosen arbitrarily; and it must appear in the wrong place. My point is there are sets that cannot be sorted according to your rules.

Comment: The `sort` utility does not do what you want?

Answer (score 0):

I don't know of any standard tool designed to perform this specific task. We can use `sort` + `awk`: sort input; compare each string with previous string, counting how many of their initial characters are the same; sort the pairs by that count in descending order. Here's an `awk` program:

```c
BEGIN {OFS = "\t"}

# Collecting pairs, so these actions are skipped for the first line
NR > 1 {
    for (i = 1; i <= len; i++)
        if (substr($0,i,1) != substr(prev,i,1))
            break
    print --i, prev, $0 \
    | "sort -k1rn,1 | cut -f2- | tr \\\\t \\\\n | awk \047!seen[$0]++\047"
    # Above pipeline can be removed to output just `--i, prev, $0`
}

{
    prev = $0
    len = length
}
```

- Requires sorted input
- Assumes input strings do not contain `TAB` characters

If input file is one string per line:

```
LC_COLLATE=C sort file | awk -f see_above.awk
```

Output:

```
Omega2
Omega23
alpha
alpine
candy3
```

---

Note: the example input data provided in the question is not enough to test with (the above output happens to be the same as `LC_COLLATE=C sort file`). To understand what is being done, here is the output of `print --i, prev, $0` (before being sorted by number, de-numbered and de-duplicated):

```
6   Omega2  Omega23
0   Omega23 alpha
3   alpha   alpine
0   alpine  candy3
```

- Consider output if alpha & alpine were changed to aaaaalpha & aaaaalpine:

```
6   Omega2  Omega23
0   Omega23 aaaaalpha
7   aaaaalpha   aaaaalpine
0   aaaaalpine  candy3
```

As they share 7 identical initial characters, aaaaalpha & aaaaalpine would appear at the top of final sorted output.